# NGRX reducers using the same state object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I have these two reducers:

```
export function reducer1(state: State = initialState,: Actions1.Actions1);
export function reducer2(state: State = initialState,: Actions2.Actions1);
```

I need those reducers to modify the same state object.

As they will use the same state object, I cannot simply split the state into small pieces to those new reducers use them [as this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970052/2992476).

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427417/splitting-big-reducer-into-smaller-reducers

Answer (score 0):

At first part you already mention that spliting reducer to small reducer so I would not mention again.

Secondly you can use [NGRX/Entity](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity) to let NGRX handle CRUD operation for you so the code complexity would be reduce because NGRX/Entity already include some API allow developer to do CRUD operation on the state.

Example:

```
const userReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(UserActions.addUser, (state, { user }) => {
    return adapter.addOne(user, state)
  }),
  on(UserActions.upsertUser, (state, { user }) => {
    return adapter.upsertOne(user, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.addUsers, (state, { users }) => {
    return adapter.addMany(users, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.upsertUsers, (state, { users }) => {
    return adapter.upsertUsers(users, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.updateUser, (state, { user }) => {
    return adapter.updateOne(user, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.updateUsers, (state, { users }) => {
    return adapter.updateMany(users, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.mapUsers, (state, { entityMap }) => {
    return adapter.map(entityMap, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.deleteUser, (state, { id }) => {
    return adapter.removeOne(id, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.deleteUsers, (state, { ids }) => {
    return adapter.removeMany(ids, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.deleteUsersByPredicate, (state, { predicate }) => {
    return adapter.removeMany(predicate, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.loadUsers, (state, { users }) => {
    return adapter.addAll(users, state);
  }),
  on(UserActions.clearUsers, state => {
    return adapter.removeAll({ ...state, selectedUserId: null });
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good suggestion to use ngrx/entity, but it is not solve the problem I have. I will edit my question with an example because I think it is not completly clear

Answer (score 0):

This solution
[Splitting big reducer into smaller reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427417/splitting-big-reducer-into-smaller-reducers)
is not exactly to your question in grabbing the same state object.

here my solution that might be solvable:

```ts
export const mergeReducers = <TState>(...reducers: ActionReducer<TState>[]): ActionReducer<TState> => {
  return (state: TState, action: Action) => {
    if (reducers.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('At least one reducer is required');
    }

    return reducers.reduce((initialState, reducer) => {
      return reducer(initialState, action);
    }, state);
  };
};
```